# what's the difference between views.list_rooms() and views.list_rooms?

Tags: python, django

I'm leargning Django, and I want to know the meaning of empty parentheses, or () follows after def name.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "app_name"

urlpatterns = [path("list", views.list_rooms())] #'list_rooms()' did not work
urlpatterns = [path("list", views.list_rooms)] #'list_rooms' did work
```

views.py

```
def list_rooms(request):
~~
```

when it was list_rooms() it raised TypeError
TypeError: list_rooms() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By doing `list_rooms()`, you are *immediately* calling the function, but by using `list_rooms`, you are passing the function in as an argument.

Running `list_room` by itself will result in an output looking like this: `<function list_rooms at 0x00000248EA961620>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see `list_rooms()` as the way to call that view (which is a function).

Whereas `list_room` is used as the name of the view here, so that you reference it.